# Yii CSqlDataProvider->getData as Float?

Tags: yii

I am trying to retreive a SQL command to use as an input parameter to another component that will convert the values from that query to a JSON enconded array. The problem is that column1 is an string and column2 is an FLOAT field.

Query Example:

```
    SELECT col1, col2
    FROM tableA
```

Consider that **col1** is a VARCHAR and **col2** is a FLOAT field.

How can I run CSqlDataProvider->getData() and have an array as:

```
    array(
      'col1' => 'value1_as_string',
      'col2' => value2_as_float_or_number  
    );
```

I can manage to run the query, but CSqlDataProvider->getData returns an array of arrays and all values are than converted to STRING as default.

How can I get an array mixed with strings and numbers with CSqlDataProvider->getData()?

Comment: You should explicitly cast it or convert it to float.

Comment: I found a related issue, but they resolved by adding a parameter to the json_encode funcion:

        $arr = array( 'row_id' => '1', 'name' => 'George' );
        echo json_encode( $arr, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK );
        //{"row_id":1,"name":"George"}
But that does not resolve my problem, because all other fields can also be treated like numbers.
I need a better solution.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have this value as Float you should convert it by using
(float)$value or floatval($value)
but maybe you should write your own

```
YourSQLProvider extends CSqlDataProvider {

   protected function fetchData(){
    $data =  parent::fetchData();

    //...parse $data ...


    return $parsedData;
   }    
}
```